# SPI interfacing a sensor doesn't seem to work

Tags: avr, spi, assembly, timing

I'm trying to get a feeling for how the SPI protocol works. I built this cirucit using **Proteus** simulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8YHzA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And then according to the datasheet, reading is done according to this protocol :

[image]

So in the code, I resorted to *bit banging* and made the following assembly:

```
    ldi r16, $0D ;
    out DDRD, r16; config input and output
    
    ldi r16, $01
    out PORTD, r16
    nop; try to insert some delay

    sbr r16 , 4; bring clk high; performs logical or with Ob100 or 4 in binary
    out PORTD, r16

    cbr r16, 4; bring clk low
    out PORTD, r16
    

    sbr r16, 4; bring clk high
    out PORTD, r16
```

The code goes on to send the full adress of the register I'm trying to read from. However the device doesn't seem to respond at all.

My first assumption is the timing that I'm not respecting. I'll attach the screenshot from the oscilloscope of the simulator:

[image]

I'm setting the appropriate bit to send on the MOSI line (yellow graph) on the falling edge, and the sampling is on the rising edge.

Green is chip select (active low) and master clock is in pink-ish.

What exactly am I doing wrong? As I see it, the logic levels might have something to do with it. If my assumption is correct, how do I remedy this?

Comment: SPI has 4 different modes based on clock phase and polarity. Try to cycle through them and see if any of them work

Comment: @ElleanorLopez This particular IC only supports 2 modes( 00 and 11)

Comment: `Ob100 or 4 in binary` so your code is setting or clearing PD2 (CSB), not PD3 (CLK). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes you're right, the mistake was in the schematic I've drawn here. I edited it. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Your protocol snippet days you're supposed to be sending 0xF6 as the control byte, but you're actually sending 0xFD.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use subroutines. Make one that sends a single bit correctly, and call that to send a byte correctly. Or directly make one that sends out a byte in a loop.

Comment: @Justme That was going to be the next step. The sending seems fine as I can see the correct bit at each rising edge. But the reply from the IC is none.

Comment: "modes 00, 11"....SPI modes are not standardized....different vendors may have different meanings to "00" or "01" and so.......so you may want to re-check the spi waveforms given in the IC data sheet and see which edge is launching and latching and what is the idle clock state, and you are complying to it.